# Find records that don't have has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables:
**advert.rb**

```
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sites, through: :postings
end
```

**posting.rb**

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :advert
  belongs_to :site
end
```

**site.rb**

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I need to find adverts that do not have postings linking them to all sites (adverts that have at least one site that they are not linked to). What query should I write?
I tried

```
Advert.joins(
  "LEFT JOIN postings ON postings.advert_id = adverts.id " +
  "JOIN sites ON sites.id = postings.site_id").
  group('adverts.id').having('COUNT(sites.id) = 0')
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

My spec:

```
site1 = create :site
site2 = create :site
advert1 = create :advert
advert2 = create :advert
create(:posting, advert: advert1, site: site1)
create(:posting, advert: advert1, site: site2)
create(:posting, advert: advert2, site: site1)
expect(Advert.not_posted).to match_array([advert2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your query:

```
Advert.includes(postings: :sites).where(sites: { id: nil })
```

You would probably want to read through [ActiveRecord querying guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: Please read my question again. I need to find all adverts without postings to at least one site. not just without postings

Comment: I added my spec to question to make my expectations clearer. Your solution returns [] which is not what I expect(

Answer (score 1):

> adverts that have at least one site that they are not linked to

So the same logic will be:

- **A** = Find the `postings` which **belong to** all `sites`
- Final result = the `adverts` which don't relate to **A**

My query like this:

```
a_query = %Q{
  SELECT advert_id
  FROM postings
  GROUP BY advert_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT site_id) = #{Site.count}
}

result = Advert.where("id NOT IN (#{a_query})")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get all Adverts do not any Site? Make it easy like this

```
Advert.where.not(id: Posting.select(:advert_id))
```